# SDL2 audio not playing correctly

Tags: go, sdl

Im making a game in Golang using SDL2 binding here : https://github.com/veandco/go-sdl2

The problem is, I added code to play audio and when I try, the audio sound is messed up. you can tell it actually played something because of the duration of the sound, and it got triggered at the right event. But the sound itself is messed up.

Here is my code :

```
package SDL

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/mix"
)

var AUDIOS map[string]*mix.Chunk

func init() {
    AUDIOS = make(map[string]*mix.Chunk)
    AUDIOS["point_normal"] = LoadAudio("sound/effects/point_normal.wav")
}

func LoadAudio(path string) *mix.Chunk {
    if err := mix.OpenAudio(44100, mix.DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 4096); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }


    // Load entire WAV data from file
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    // Load WAV from data (memory)
    chunk, err := mix.QuickLoadWAV(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }
    defer chunk.Free()
    return chunk
}

func CloseAudio() {
    mix.CloseAudio()
}
```

And here is the sound I try to play :

https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/point_normal.wav

Can someone see anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the sound library you're using, but these lines look suspicious to me:

```
defer chunk.Free()
return chunk
```

The returned "chunk" will have Free() called on it. Is that really what you intended?

Comment: You are right. That line was an error. I removed it, still the sound is not working fine. For some reason, it plays well only 3 time snow. The 4th time it starts getting messed.

Comment: One potential problem could be the values you use for OpenAudio, but I am not familiar with the library, so that's just a guess. I can't see anything wrong with the code you posted, maybe there's something wrong in the sections you didn't post?

Comment: the code outside of this is pretty straight forward. I just run SDL.AUDIOS["point_normal"].Play(-1,1). Now I changed the wav for another file and it kinda works. But only EXACTLY three times. The fourth time it gets messed up